# Find the line which makes angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with $(2-i)z+(2+i)\overline z+3=0$ which passes through point $(-1,4)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the line which makes angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with $(2-i)z+(2+i)\overline z+3=0$ which passes through point $(-1,4)$.
Complex slope of the given line is $$ w_1=\frac{-3-4i}{5}$$
The complex slope of the line which makes angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with $(2-i)z+(2+i)\overline z+3=0$ will be $$w_2=\frac{4-3i}{5} $$ And hence the equation of the line will be given by $$\frac{z-(-1+4i)}{\overline z-(-1-4i)}=\frac{4-3i}{5} $$
But this does not give the correct answer and it is not of the form $\overline \alpha z +\alpha \overline z+\beta=0$. Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint use rotation matrix which is $$(\begin{matrix} cos(\theta)& sin(\theta)\\-sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{matrix})$$. Now you have point and equation use it with it and get the required line